Add unique value to a key in Kafka message using Kouncil
I have a json payload that I am using to produce a kafka message via Kouncil, json is as below:
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "id": "product-1730976584",
    "source": "product-service"
}

I want to generate lot of these messages and need a unique product id every time. In the example above I have used epoch in seconds (as suffix), and I am doing this thing manually for every event. 
Is there a way I can add a timestamp kind of suffix to achieve this? Something like "id": "product-{{epochInSeconds}}"
I am using epoch here, but it can be any uique id generator (like UUID or anything else) 
I am aware of how to achieve this for HTTP APIs via Postman.

EDIT: As suffix need not be a numeric value, how about having <topicName>-<partitionId>-<offset> as a suffix , it will be unique but is there a way to use these as a placeholder variables?

I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking about Kouncil or just kafka, in general. If the latter, look at ShadowTraffic

I want to publish an event from Kouncil and I want this thing to be in Kouncil

Does Kouncil have an individual support channel? https://docs.kouncil.io/getting-started/faq
